# Преобразовывание спец. символов XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Есть текст, в котором есть &lt,&gt и т п ESCAPE символы XML.

Подскажите, есть ли стандартные способы преобразования этого в человеческий текст?

(Где вместо ESCAPE символов используются нормальные символы)

Или можно исправить проблему банальным, последовательным REPLACE?

Comment: а чем `Replace` не угодил?

Comment: Ничем, просто хотел узнать, что Мб есть что то родное

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
string encoded = "(A &gt; B) &amp; (C &lt; D)";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
string xml = string.Format("<a>{0}</a>", encoded);
doc.LoadXml(xml);
string decoded = doc.DocumentElement.InnerText; //(A > B) & (C < D)
```

или

```
string encoded = "(A &gt; B) &amp; (C &lt; D)";

using (var sr = new StringReader(string.Format("<a>{0}</a>", encoded)))
using (var xr = XmlReader.Create(sr))
{
    xr.MoveToContent();
    string decoded = xr.ReadElementContentAsString(); //(A > B) & (C < D)
}
```

Comment: То что нужно. Спасибо